# horizontal scrollbar not showing in listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, horizontal-scrolling

I have a usercontrol that contains a listbox (listbox1).

The horizontalscrollbar setting is set to TRUE.

There is also an handler on another listbox (selectionchanged) that sets the values for the listbox1 (in case this might cause the problem).

I add this usercontrol to a tabpage in a tabcontrol.

The problem I am facing is that the horizontalscrollbar is not shown even if the items displayed in listbox1 are bigger than the width.

Anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

-EDIT-
as requested as much code as I can show

```
dim tabpage as new Tabpage
dim dict as new dictionary(of String, list(of MyObject))
'fill dict
tabpage.add(usercontrol(dict))
tabcontrol1.tabpages.add(tabpage)
```

usercontrol:

```
class UserControl  
 public sub new(dict)
  Dim bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource(dict, Nothing)
    ListBox1.DataSource = bs
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"
 end sub  

 Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListBox2.DataSource = New BindingSource(CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of MyObject))).Value, Nothing)
        End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should probably consider showing some code.

Comment: there is not much code to show. listbox added to usercontrol using designer and set the property of horizontalscrollbar to true in the desinger as well. Then added usercontrol added to a tabpage. will post something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why it didnt work. Was just a small setting I overlooked.
Am posting this here as it might help other people.

If the listbox has **multiColumn** set to **True** then the horizontal scrollbar will not be displayed as you(I) would like to.

Turning off the multiColumn (when not needed) or fixing the column width will fix this issue.

Topic can be closed.